# Unbind events on elements that will be added to DOM later

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, unbind

I have a div with class="backdrop". This will be added to DOM when I click a button. To this is bound an event of 'wheel'.

I cannot avoid the binding of the event(happening through library) So i will want to unbind this globally.

I tried : `$(".modal-backdrop.am-fade").unbind('wheel');`

This works but I have to write this statement after each time the div is added to the DOM. `I want something which I can write only once and would apply to all the divs which would be added to the DOM in future`

Comment: Have you tried a more global selector like `$(window).unbind(`

Comment: But that would unbind the wheel event from all the elements under window.. I want to unbind only from .modal-backdrop.am-fade

Comment: I mean like editing the prototype to remove the event handler

Comment: Nope i havent tried that.. was looking for one stop fix using .off() or something

Comment: As .on() works to delegate event, i thought and was hoping .off() could take then out also in a deleagated sort of way

Comment: @BhumiSinghal: It's a reasonable thought, but no, it doesn't work that way. If the library is binding events directly to the elements, you can't use a delegated handler to prevent those handlers being run.

Comment: Hmm .. sadness ... I modified the library eventually.

Answer (score 0):

> I want something which I can write only once and would apply to all the divs which would be added to the DOM in future

If code in the library you're using is adding elements and binding events to them, you'll have to unbind them as you go, there's no alternative.

If you already have some way of triggering that (the library tells you when it adds a div), then you'll just have to have that code respond to that event.

If you *don't* already have some way of triggering it, you can use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for the divs being added so you can unbind them. They're well-supported by modern browsers. Slightly less modern browsers may have sufficient support for the old mutation *events* that you can use a library that provides a mutation observer polyfill using mutation events (just search for "mutation observer polyfill"). Worst case, on really old browsers, you'll have to poll.

---

Of course, the best answer is to either stop using the library if it doesn't do what you want, or modify it (this is JavaScript, after all) so it doesn't do what you don't want.

Comment: the library is angularstrap .. too much code .. too risky .. cant change

Comment: @BhumiSinghal: There's a difference between "can't" and "choose not to because it's too big." In any case, that was just a postscript to the main point of the answer.

Comment: :) so i choose not ot